# Existence of local minimizer

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, differential-calculus

For a $f\in C^3$ function, if there is a sufficiently small $\epsilon$

$$\| \nabla F(x) \| < \epsilon$$

and a sufficiently large $\alpha$ where

$$\lambda_{\min}[\nabla^2 F(x)] \ge \alpha$$

Can we conclude that there is a local minimizer $x^*$ in a small neighborhood $B(x,\delta)$ of $F(x)$?

This is obviously true in one dimension, by mean-value theorem. I wonder if it holds in higher dimension.

Comment: What exactly is "obviously true" in one dimension? You won't be able to deduce anything from just $f',f''$ at a single point (you'd need the second condition on a not too small open set).

Comment: In one dimensions, we have $f'(x) = f'(0) + \left[\int_0^1 f''(tx) dt\right] x \ge -\epsilon + \alpha x$. Therefore $f'(\alpha/\epsilon) \ge 0$, and by Darboux theorem, we conclude there exists a $x_*\in [0,alpha/\epsilon]$ that $f'(x_*) = 0$, which is a local minimizer.